# Error on retrieving array length in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've been trying to run a simple script that retrieves the penultimate subdirectory of a variable size directory. But it fails miserably to retrieve its length. The script goes:

```
ARRAY=$(ls files-0/var/log/)

echo ${#ARRAY[@]}

for i in ${#ARRAY[@]};
do
    echo $i
done
```

The output I get is:

1

1

If i change the line

```
for i in ${#ARRAY[@]};
```

by

```
for i in $ARRAY;
```

at least I get the list of directories/files:

```
53513
53514
53515
...
```

I know there are lot's of posts approaching this question, but mostly all of them start from the basis of getting array length properly.

Comment: Try: `ARRAY=( $(ls files-0/var/log/) )`

Comment: I wouldn't say that "works well", for all the reasons given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. `array=( files-0/var/log/* )` would be a much safer / more reliable way to populate an array (and then `array=( "${array[@]##*/}" )` if one doesn't want the directory names present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comment, the syntax for initializing indexed array values in BASH is:

```
array=( element1 element2 etc... )
```

In your case you were simply assigning the result of the command substitution to the array with:

```
ARRAY=$(ls files-0/var/log/)
```

(which assigned the return of `ls files-0/var/log/` to a variable named `ARRAY`)

The proper initialization of the `ARRAY` using command substitution is:

```
ARRAY=( $(ls files-0/var/log/) )
```

**Note:** when an array is declared with `declare -a somename`, or after it has been initialized with values, you can add an element to the array in the next open index with:

```
ARRAY+=( somevalue )  # quoted as necessary
```

As of BASH 4, you also have `Associative Arrays` (declare -A) which allow arrays to be created with `key` `value` pairs, instead of simple `index` `value` pairs. Where initialization is:

```
AARRAY=( [key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 etc... )
```

Good luck with BASH, it is a very capable shell.

Comment: Describing `$(ls ...)` as "correct" or a good practice is somewhat suspect. That's hitting directly on BashPitfalls #1, after all -- from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls -- and in contravention of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: `array=( files-0/var/log/* ); array=( "${array[@]##*/}" )` would be the safer alternative.

Comment: Agreed to both comments Charles, I was attempting to stick to the approach taken, but it would have been better to populate the array in a more conventional manner.

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
for dir in "${ARRAY}[@]"
do
  echo "$dir"
done
```

Could you give us an example of what input/output you want?

Comment: did you test it? It should be `"${array[@]}"`

Comment: yes, i tested, it works for listing directories. But i have the feeling that i do not fully understand what he wants

Comment: Already said before that the answer from David C. Rankin was correct. Thank you